# Install windows 8 on the same machine twice

Tags: windows-8, windows-installer

Recently I bought and installed Windows 8 Professional. Some time later I bought an SSD drive and cloned the original disk (with Windows 8 on it) to the new one.

Now I have problems with it, since I forgot to change partition align and some other things, I have some problems with this installation at startup (strange errors appear when the computer wakes up from hibernation).

I want to do a clean install to the SSD drive, but my Windows copy is already activated. If I format my SSD drive and install Windows 8 Professional on it, can I use the activation key that I have already used, to activate the new Windows installation? 
All hardware is the same, except for the hard drive.

Comment: A simple hard drive or minor hardware change shouldn't cause any problems at all with activation. Otherwise lots of people would be up in arms.

Comment: Even if I run installation and activation process twice?

Comment: Yep, every time you reinstall you'd need to re-activate. If they restricted it to just a single activation and didn't allow for the possibility of any hardware changes, they'd be shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: I second that. I can't cite anyone, but I've done this a whole lot of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question. Yes you can reuse your Windows 8 key regardless of hardware changes or machine.

Edit: With 10 reuses as Karan has explained. (Thanks! :)

Comment: ... within limits (I believe it's [10 activations per key](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-windows_install/how-many-activations-do-the-win8-retail-key-have/e53834e0-d31a-4c51-9920-af1cca4b357f) if hardware has changed).