# Swapping Windows 8 and 7 across two machines

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 brought as a stand alone vanilla and recently bought Windows 8 pro too. Both direct from Microsoft. Both have been installed and activated. 8 once and 7 several times on the same machine. I want to swap the two OS on to the other machines. The 8 onto the more powerful machine and 7 on to the lesser.

Can I do a straight switch?

And if I want to switch back at a later date can I do that too? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you want.

Microsoft allows a certain number of reactivations (I'm not sure of the exact number) to cater for cases where you have to replace hardware or even rebuild machines.

As the Windows 8 reinstall is only the 2<sup>nd</sup> activation you should have no problem at all.

You *might* experience problems with the Windows 7 reactivation, but a call to Microsoft support in your region should sort that out. It should be obvious that you aren't installing it on several machines - especially if you install Windows 8 first.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure how well it would go down. You mention second for 8, is there a limit?

Comment: @KarlSadler - There probably is a limit, but I expect Microsoft to keep it secret. All I meant was that the limit is almost certainly higher than 2. In all my times of reinstalling OSes I've never had to ring Microsoft.

Comment: @KarlSadler: See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/495229/install-windows-8-on-the-same-machine-twice#comment590489_495234).